# Join to int[] column of foreign keys and select as json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two tables that I would like to join. This is what I would like the output to look like.

```
{'id': 1, 
'description': None, 
'name': 'admin', 
'scope_id': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'default', 'color': 'primary'}, 
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'admin', 'color': 'secondary'}]
```

Here are the tables:

Group

```
id   | name   | description   | scope_id
---- | ------ | ------------- | ---------
1    | admin  | None          | [1,2]
```

Scope

```
id   | name     | color   
---- | -------- | --------
1    | default  | Primary     
2    | admin    | Secondary
```

I can't figure out how to do this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the two tables: you can do the following:

select g.*, s.*
  from "group" g
    join scope s on s.id = any(g.scope_id);

One way to generate the JSON is:

```
select to_jsonb(g) - 'scope_id' || 
       jsonb_build_object('scope_id', (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s)) 
                                       from scope s 
                                       where s.id = any(g.scope_id))
                         )
from "group" g;
```

`to_jsonb(g) - 'scope_id'` turns the whole row into a JSON and then removes the `scope_id` key. The aggregation of the corresponding `scope` rows is then appended to that JSON.

Another way to write the above is:

```
select to_jsonb(g) - 'scope_id' || jsonb_build_object('scope_id', s)
from "group" g
  left join lateral (
       select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as scope_id
       from scope s 
       where s.id = any(g.scope_id)
  ) s on true
```

Alternatively, if `id` is the primary key of the `"Group"` table, you can do the following:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select g.id, g.name, g.description, 
         json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as scope_id
  from "group" g
    join scope s on s.id = any(g.scope_id)
  group by g.id
) t;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/JNV28258